# How to send email non activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I need send email so, I created a class but an error appears in startActivity(intent). this code works well in a Main Activity. here the code:

```
public class SendEmail extends Activity {
private String emailTo;
private String subject;
private String message;

public SendEmail(String AEmailTo, String ASubject, String AMessage) {
    this.emailTo = AEmailTo;
    this.subject = ASubject;
    this.message = AMessage;
}

public void Send(){
     try {          
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("application/octet-stream");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, this.subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, this.message);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {this.emailTo});
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
       } catch (Exception e) {   
         Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
       }
    }
```

}

LogCat:

```
11-12 10:54:56.783: E/SendMail(19773): null
11-12 10:54:56.783: E/SendMail(19773): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 10:54:56.783: E/SendMail(19773):  at    android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
11-12 10:54:56.783: E/SendMail(19773):  at    android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
11-12 10:54:56.783: E/SendMail(19773):  at   idealbrasil.forcav.android.SendEmail.Send(SendEmail.java:52)
11-12 10:54:56.783: E/SendMail(19773):  at idealbrasil.forcav.android.util.funcoes.SendEmail(funcoes.java:221)
11-12 10:54:56.783: E/SendMail(19773):  at idealbrasil.forcav.android.util.TrataErro$1.onClick(TrataErro.java:136)
11-12 10:54:56.783: E/SendMail(19773):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
11-12 10:54:56.783: E/SendMail(19773):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 10:54:56.783: E/SendMail(19773):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-12 10:54:56.783: E/SendMail(19773):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
```

Comment: You need to post the relevant part of your code as well as the exact error you are getting. Otherwise no one would be able to help.

Comment: Are you calling `SendEmail()` before `Send()`?

Comment: new SendEmail(constantes.EmailTo, "Mensagem de Erro", msn).Send();

Comment: I think you need to clear Android Activity tutorials once again. !

Comment: Where are you using that line of code?

Comment: your activity is not created. you cannot call startActivity before onCreate was called (by the system). What is the context / post the code where you call SendMail(...).Send()

Comment: I new in android. I'm trying fix bugs in this app. I need send email with app error

Answer (score 0):

The context there is null, for startActivity(), which is the reason you are getting a nullpointer exception. Looks like you are new to Android, and the process is not according to coding conventions.

You may either use onCreate() method in the class, and then class startActivity(), or pass a context to this function, and call

`context.startActivity(intent);`